# Confusion about how arguments are passed through Python decorators

Tags: python, decorator, python-2.x

TL;DR: Does a decorated function have the argument requirements (in terms of argument count and kwarg names) as the same function undecorated, if the function decorator doesn't specifically specify arguments?

I have a controller for a web app which handles all of the shopping cart ajax calls. At the start of each call it initializes an object which handles the actual logic of the shopping cart functionality. (That may not be the most efficient way to go about it, but my question doesn't have anything to do with the actual shopping cart bit.)

The code looks like this:

```
from webapp import request

from shopping_cart import Cart
from decorators import decorator

@decorator
def init_cart(f, *args, **kwargs):
    shopping_cart = Cart()
    return f(shopping_cart = cart)

@init_cart
def add_item(shopping_cart = None):
    shopping_cart.add(request.params)

@init_cart
def remove_item(shopping_cart = None):
    shopping_cart.remove(request.params)
```

And so forth.

That code exists in a centralized module, which is imported and called by several apps. The code in the individual apps looks like this:

```
from sharedlib.controllers import cart
from app.base import *

class CartController(BaseController):

    def index(self, url = None):
        set_content_type('text/javascript')
        controller_method = getattr(cart, url)
        if controller_method:
            return controller_method()
        else:
            abort(404)
```

My question is as follows:

If I want the init_cart decorator to pass on the arguments it receives to the controller method being called, in addition to passing the cart module, I would try:

```
@decorator
def init_cart(f, *args, **kwargs):
    shopping_cart = Cart()
    kwargs['shopping_cart'] = cart
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

@init_cart
def add_item(shopping_cart = None):
    shopping_cart.add(request.params)
```

but I get an exception thrown, `TypeError: add_item() got multiple values for keyword argument 'shopping_cart'`

I do not fully understand this behaviour: kwargs, surely, has only one key/value pair for 'shopping_cart'.

Moreover, if I try this:

```
@decorator
def init_cart(f, *args, **kwargs):
    shopping_cart = Cart()
    return f(cart)

@init_cart
def add_item(shopping_cart = None):
    shopping_cart.add(request.params)
```

I get the error `TypeError: add_item() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

I am assuming that I somehow don't grok how decorators are behaving when it comes to receiving and passing arguments -- I assumed that if `init_cart` used `(*args, **kwargs)` then the functions it decorates could be called with any set of arguments, or lackthereof. That seems to not be the case.

Furthermore, in the previous example, how is it possible for the method to be receiving multiple values for the `shopping_cart` argument?

Comment: what is `Cart` if it is returning a tuple or something i could see that breaking?

Comment: `Cart` is a class that's being initialized. The idea was to use the `shopping_cart` variable to pass around the instance of the `Cart` being used in each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that Joran was partially right in his answer: although my understanding of decorators when written by hand was not incorrect, I had completely failed to understand what the `decorator.decorator` decorator was doing when using it to ease the creation of them.

This largely has to do with how the `decorator` module attempts to determine the argspec of the function it is decorating. The easiest way to demonstrate this behaviour is to compare a decorator made with `@decorator.decorator` to one made manually (the passing around of another object has been replaced with the passing of a string, for experimental purposes):

```
import decorator

@decorator.decorator
def init_cart(f, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['shopping_cart'] = 'cart'
    print args, kwargs
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

@init_cart
def add_item(shopping_cart = None):
    print shopping_cart


def init_cart2(f):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['shopping_cart'] = 'cart'
        print args, kwargs
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapped


@init_cart2
def add_item2(shopping_cart = None):
    print shopping_cart
```

So `add_item2` will always use the manual decorator, `add_item` will use the helper from the `decorator` module.

I would have expected that in both cases calling `add_item(shopping_cart = 'some value')` would always cause `'cart'` to be printed (in both cases, the argument is a keyword argument, overwritten by the decorating function). Instead, the following results (with both decorators printing the arguments they are sending to the wrapped function):

```
>>> add_item(shopping_cart = 'some_value')
('some_value',) {'shopping_cart': 'cart'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 2, in add_item
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in init_cart
TypeError: add_item() got multiple values for keyword argument 'shopping_cart'
```

And:

```
>>> add_item2(shopping_cart = 'some_value')
() {'shopping_cart': 'cart'}
cart
```

In the first example, `init_cart` isn't receiving the arguments as keyword arguments.

Looking at the code of the `decorator` module, it becomes clearer why this is so:

```
def decorator(caller, func=None):
    """
    decorator(caller) converts a caller function into a decorator;
    decorator(caller, func) decorates a function using a caller.
    """
    if func is None: # returns a decorator
        fun = FunctionMaker(caller)
        first_arg = inspect.getargspec(caller)[0][0]
        src = 'def %s(%s): return _call_(caller, %s)' % (
            caller.__name__, first_arg, first_arg)
        return fun.make(src, dict(caller=caller, _call_=decorator),
                        undecorated=caller)
    else: # returns a decorated function
        fun = FunctionMaker(func)
        src = """def %(name)s(%(signature)s):
    return _call_(_func_, %(signature)s)"""
        return fun.make(src, dict(_func_=func, _call_=caller), undecorated=func)
```

It appears that the wrapped `init_cart` function was not being called in *precisely* the same way as it's wrapper was being called, hence my confusion.

In hindsight, that makes much more sense, and is probably what I get for using a helper whose behaviour I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
def this_is_a_decorator(fn):
    def decorated_fn(*args,**kwargs):
        result = fn(*args,**kwargs) #notice we are calling the original function
        return "%s decorated"%result
    return decorated_fn

@this_is_a_decorator
def reverse_string(msg=""):
    return msg[::-1]

print reverse_string("Hello!")
```

for the decorator for you

```
def init_cart(fn):
    def decorated_fn(*args,**kwargs):
        cart = Cart()
        fn(cart)
        return cart
    return decorated_fn

@init_cart
def add_item(shopping_cart=None):
     shopping_cart.add(request.params)
```

Comment: While I don't mean to be difficult, you haven't provided me with any more information than what is available in the Python documentation. I think I understand how decorators work generally (which your code demonstrates), which is why I am confused; unless I am missing something terribly obvious, I think the decorator's calling of the passed function matches the passed function's argspec in each of my examples above, yet the latter two examples both throw exceptions. That's what I can't figure out.

Comment: my example with init_cart should do what you want ... i dont know what the decorator decorator is doing ... you obviously are lacking some understanding of how decorators generally work, since yours does not work, and your question does not make clear your general understanding of decorators which is why i provided a very simple decorator example

Comment: I think I may have come across as slightly combative, so apologies. What I'm trying to figure out may be down to how the `decorator` module's decorator factory function is working -- you're right that your example would indeed work as written.